# How can I include an html snippet (for a bootstrap modal) in another html file?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, requirejs, single-page-application

So I am trying to build up a small app that uses html/knockout/web api.

I don't want to use Durandal or another navigation framework like that if I can do it without.

I currently have three separate html pages all of which access (via a common datacontext) protected data methods that require authentication.  If the datacontext receives a 401 error after accessing the Web Api, I want to pop up a bootstrap modal with login functionality so the user can authenticate themselves and carry on where they left off.

I have sort of achieved this by cheating and using asp.net web forms with a login user control that contains the login functionality. This user control is included in the three separate pages. However I'm now getting bogged down with complexities involving script loading order and dependencies so I'd like to bring this all back to a simpler basis using plain html if possible.

What I want to avoid is having to have the html code for the bootstrap modal being duplicated in every single HTML page as this would be massively inefficient, but I don't see how I can achieve the functionality I want without doing just that at the moment.

Is this possible to do or do I need to go even further back and make this a single page application and inject viewmodels as needed?  The last option takes me closer to (or to) a Durandal-style app which I'm trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: There are very many things going on at once in your question. First, you mention "html/knockout/web-api", but later you talk about web forms controls, and even later you ask if you should go "back to a spa" (the first option *is* a spa setup...). You also mix in componentizing your views and lazy loading of parts of it. IMHO you should go back to the drawing board, maybe read a tutorial or two on these subjects and return with a more specific question.

Comment: 3 separate html pages is not really what I'd call a single page application, but I think some of your points have merit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `load()` function to retrieve HTML and then inject it into the Bootstrap modal, like this:

```
$('#your-selector').on('click', function () {
    $('#your-modal-selector').load('/your-file.html ', function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
            $($this).modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks interesting, thank you. Will experiment with it and see how it works for me.